# Is defining measures as functionals ever insufficiently general in practice?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Edit: Crossposted to [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462986/is-defining-measures-as-functionals-ever-insufficiently-general-in-practice)

---

The way I learned measures was as set functions on a $\sigma$-algebra with certain properties. However, I'm aware of another viewpoint, used for example in Bourbaki's *Integration*, that defines measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces to be functionals on the space of compactly-supported continuous functions. This is obviously less general, but I suppose the argument is that most measures that arise in practice are Radon measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

The counterpoint that I keep seeing cited is that this is insufficient for probability theory. In *Real and Complex Analysis* (p. 35), Rudin mentions the Wiener measure as an example of a measure that doesn't fall into this framework. However, I have also seen some sources say that the needs of probability theory can be met by extending the theory to general Hausdorff spaces. I've heard this as Bourbaki's rationale for adding a 9th chapter to *Integration* about measures on Hausdorff spaces (see for instance p. 14 of [this review](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/11/11-169.pdf?)), and in the introduction to *Radon Measures on Arbitrary Topological Spaces and Cylindrical Measures*, Schwartz says

> The fundamental defect of the usual theory of Radon measures is that the spaces of functions which occur in the theory of probability are not locally compact.

> The present theory of Radon measures on arbitrary (for the most part) Hausdorff topological spaces combines all the advantages of both methods [i.e., in terms of sets and in terms of functionals]...

My question is: does extending the functional approach to Hausdorff spaces actually make it general enough for the needs of probability theory? If not, are there examples of probabilistic concepts that are less easy (or impossible) to describe from this viewpoint? (I would also be happy to hear about fields other than probability for which this viewpoint does not suffice, if they exist.)

Comment: The real historical reason why Bourbaki chose such way to present Measure Theory is that, when it came to the time for Bourbaki to publish its book on Measure Theory, Halmos (an American mathematician) had just published his book Measure Theory. Halmos was not member of Bourbaki, but his rigorous style was very close to the Bourbaki style.

So, at that time, Bourbaki group had to choose another approach to write their book.

Comment: @Ramiro Interesting. Do you happen to have a source for this?

Comment: Also note that Bourbaki's *Éléments de mathématique* contains no probability theory.

Comment: @JustinToyota: It is actually not less general. Dropping the topology and considering just the basic principles, Daniell and (then throughout the work of Stone) a method of integration can be developed via linear functionals on a space of functions with some algebraic and order conditions (a ring closed under chopping or a vector lattice of bounded functions). It turns out, that measure theory can be develop from this approach as a consequence of the construction.

Comment: @Mittens I've heard of the Daniell integral but don't know much about it. Is the approach on locally compact spaces just the Daniell approach with the elementary functions being the compactly-supported continuous functions?

Comment: @JustinToyota: The technique is applicable for abstract integration theory (no underlying topology). The key elements is a set $\mathcal{E}$ go bounded functions (defined on a common set $S$) with some algebraic+order structure: a ring lattice or a Stone lattice, and a linear functional $I$ defined on $\mathcal{E}$ that satisfies some continuity conditions (a weak version of monotone convergence).